# c++ weird number output format setf(ios::scientific)

Tags: c++, format, output, iostream, flags

I have

```
int main()
{
    double a = 12.34567;
    cout.setf(ios::fixed);
    cout.setf(ios::scientific);
    cout<<a;
return 0;
}
```

The output is 0x1.8b0fba8826aa9p+3

If I unset the ios::fixed flag, the result is OK,  1.234567e+01. Please help to explain it. Thank you!

code is here http://ideone.com/7qrjgg

Comment: integer seems strange in this context

Comment: @JacekCz, my bad, it should be double

Comment: code should be include here, not in external sources

Comment: `0x1.8b0fba8826aa9p+3` is a [hex float literal](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/floating_literal)

Comment: @LưuVĩnhPhúc hi, i still dont understand why ios::fixed causes such behavior.

Comment: Thanks @luu now i see the problem